# Check whether Google BigQuery is using GCS buckets or any other storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, cloud, bigtable

I am very new to Google Cloud.
I was querying some public datasets in google BigQuery.
I wanted to know if there was any possible way in which we can know whether the data being queried is from a Google Cloud bucket.

I have tried using T-SQL queries on it but it didnt work.

Any kind of storage metadata regarding the dataset that I am scanning would be useful.

Is it even possible to know whether the queried dataset is from a Google Cloud Bucket? If yes, how would I find where the bucket is located?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could scan the [relevant INFORMATION_SCHEMA view](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-tables) for tables of type EXTERNAL, which would identify which tables are potentially defined against an external source such as Cloud Storage.  However, that view doesn't expose the details of the external definition, so you'd need to fallback to inspecting the tables individually (or via something like tables.get in the API) to get all the details since you appear to be after specific storage URIs.

As for the location of a bucket, such a thing would need to be interrogated against another source such as the cloud storage libraries, or a tool such as the cloud console or the gsutil command.

Comment: So if I use the tables.get API I would be able to get where the table is actually stored?
If you could point me to some documentation on this that would be really useful!

Comment: You can use tables.get to identify the BigQuery notion of location, but if it's defined against a cloud storage bucket that may be a slightly different location.  https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/samples/bigquery-get-table are relevant BQ samples, and https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/samples/storage-get-bucket-metadata for cloud storage examples.

Comment: But if I wanted to know if the BQ is querying a cloud bucket or some other storage location, could I do that?

Comment: [Query statistics](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/Job#JobStatistics2) can include a list of referenced tables which you can then check, but there's nothing directly in the query stats that indicates storage URIs or anything, if that's what you're asking.